# Is there a way to monitor timescaleDB statefulset pod using Prometheus itself?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, timescaledb

I am using `Prometheus` + `promscale` + `timescaleDB` + `grafana` to monitor my kubernetes cluster. I tried using `postgress-exporter` to listen to `timescaleDB` metrics but the queries did not work. And there is no `timescale-exporter`. How does one show timescale metrics on `grafana`?

Comment: Hello, can you provide a bit more info about your setup. 
1. Are you using the timescaledb-single helm chart, or by chance tobs (github.com/timescale/tobs) helm chart to deploy the stack you mentioned?
2. Which data source are you querying, prometheus, promscale (as a prom data source), or TimescaleDB (as a postgres data source)
3. Do other metrics appear in grafana (that is, are the other pod metrics collected by prometheus)?

Comment: Using timescale DB as a statefulset. Using promscale-connector to connect to prometheus.
Other pod metrics appear on grafana . I want to use postgres-exporter to check health of timescale.